# Selecting a Range of Numbers while joining

Tags: sql, common-table-expression

I'm selecting a range of numbers 1-6 with a CTE. I have another table that has two columns. One with any number between 1-6 and a column called code.

I want to always return 1-6 but join on my other table that has the code.

An Example would be:

```
Table 1
Number
------
1
2
3
4
5
6


Table 2
   Number | Code
   ------   -----
    1         B
    3         A
    5         C
```

I want the Select to return:

```
CodeNumber | Code
------       -----
1             B
2            NULL
3             A
4            NULL
5             C
6            NULL
```

If I join on the number it doesn't return all the values.

```
DECLARE @Start INT 
DECLARE @End INT
DECLARE @Priority CHAR(2)
SELECT  @Start = -3
      , @End = 3
      , @Code = ''

WITH    Numbers (Number, Code)
          AS ( SELECT   @Start AS Number, @Code
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   Number + 1, @Code
               FROM     Numbers
               WHERE    Number < @End
             )
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`:

```
WITH Numbers(Number) as (
       SELECT   @Start AS Number
       UNION ALL
       SELECT   Number + 1
       FROM     Numbers
       WHERE    Number < @End
      )
select n.number, t.code
from numbers n left join
     table2 t
     on t.number = n.number;
```

Comment: My problem is if I JOIN on the table1 number and table2 doesn't contain that number..it won't pull the range 1-6. It will pull like 1,2,4,6 for each code.

Comment: @user2531854 . . . THis will return the `select` as you have defined it.  Try it.